# Update query and not replace existing result, just combine old result + new result with comma

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to do a Update query but not replace existing result, combine both result with comma become array. My query will be something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE outlet_type_location SET treatment_id = **',$id'** WHERE outlet_type_id = '$outlet_type_id'";
```

Thanks for everyone giving me advice.

Comment: you mean something like this? `UPDATE outlet_type_location SET treatment_id = concat(treatment_id,',','$id') WHERE outlet_type_id = '$outlet_type_id'`?

Comment: @roullie yes!!! Exactly the answer I wish to get. Thank you so much dude!!

Comment: glad i helped.  have a nice day

Comment: @roullie do you know how can I get the data from concat(); My query is as $treatment_id = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["treatment_id"]));

$query = "SELECT * FROM outlet_type_location WHERE treatment_id = '$treatment_id'";
$result = $db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array();

I need to search treatment_id in outlet_type_location, I just tried treatment_id IN ($treatment_id) but didn't get it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET` like this

```
SELECT * FROM outlet_type_location WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$treatment_id',treatment_id) > 0
```

Comment: @rouline Thank you so much :)